# MySQL "Host" permissions

Tags: mysql

Exactly what is the best way to configure this?  I have a user account for a web app specified, but I also want to connect to the database via a GUI.  The host is specified as `%` but the GUI tool repeatedly says access denied although I am using the proper password.  If I change this to `localhost` then I can connect via the command line, but not via the GUI.  If I add two entries, then I can connect via the command line and not the GUI.  Leaving only the `%` doesn't let me connect via the command line OR the GUI.  I want to be able to connect both on the actual server (via the web app itself) AND via the GUI tool.

Comment: How are you setting the permissions?

Comment: Is the GUI tool on the same host?  How are you connecting, through the socket or through tcp/ip? Can you connect using the mysql command?

Comment: What's your GRANT statement look like?

Comment: grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'user'@'%' with grant option;

Comment: No password?  Not sure if you omitted that on purpose for the comment, or if it's just missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention that you have ever been able to connect using the GUI tool. If you haven't then I suspect that the problem is not with mysql's permissions, but with the GUI tool's config.

If I'm misinterpreting, please clarify under what circumstances you were able to connect using the GUI.

Comment: Not to this server, but to other servers with the same kind of install.  I've tried using two different GUIs (Sequel Pro and Navicat for MySQL) and both give me a permission denied error although I've followed the same procedure as I always have.